# Outputting X^n without caret

Tags: java, android, string, math

I am writing a simple android app and I would like to set the text of a button to be X^n but I want it to look the same way as it would if you would write it on a piece of paper( for example 2⁶).

I know there are several unicode characters that does it for a small group of numbers but I am looking for a generel function (or any other way) that takes two integers and output the first by the power of the second. For example:

```
int X=2;
int n=6;
function(X , n) ==> 2⁶
```

I know a similar question was asked here before but its answers were not sufficient because I want to use variables' values and not actual numbers;

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use html's `<sup>` tags for that:

```
button.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>n</sup>"));
```

Comment: Yes but I want X and n to be Variables not to give their actual value.
Like:
int X = 2;
int n = 6;
button.setText(Html.fromHtml("X<sup>n</sup>")); ==> 2⁶

Comment: @user3293135 you can use simple java concatenation with variables.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?